# How to get mysql queries if contition is matched and yet have a fallback

Tags: mysql

While the title is broad, then my question is simple. I have a table, lets call it "news", where are articles. Normally articles are being pulled by `order`, but on the frontpage they are being displayed only if they are "featured". However, if the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM {TABLE_PREFIX}news WHERE `status` = '1' AND `featured` = '1' ORDER BY `order` LIMIT 0, 4
```

Then at least some articles must be featured.. However, what if there are only 2 featured articles? So I would like to have a fallback, so when there are only 2 featured articles, it would also get two non-featured.

I thought that, this would do the trick, but it doesn't work like I planned it:

```
SELECT * FROM {TABLE_PREFIX}news WHERE `status` = '1' AND `featured` = '1' ORDER BY `featured`, `order` LIMIT 0, 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you still select on `featured = 1`. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM {TABLE_PREFIX}news WHERE `status` = '1' ORDER BY `featured` DESC, `order` LIMIT 0, 4
```

Comment: Oh right right, "Dont code while tired". Thanks for the quick reply, works like charm :) You were so fast, that have to wait for 7 minutes to accept.